# Edited data in table should change in chart and other components angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a datatable, chart, and Latest value added label.

- Table and chart are displaying time-series data that contains: the value time for the last 30 minutes and its numerical random value from 0 to 999.
- Every 10 seconds new object gets pushed into the array and the oldest one is deleted so only the last 30 minutes are showing all the time.
- Latestvalue label is displaying the latest value added

I am trying to figure out how to implement editing of the rows in the table so when I edit any of the rows either time or its random value or both I also want to display the change on the chart. Also for some reason the chart is not updating like the table every 10 seconds.

How can I achieve that ? Any help appreciated.

Here is working stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znnnsp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.html,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Flabel%2Flabel.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Flabel%2Flabel.component.css,package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in you chart component you seem to initialize the chart just once initially on ngOnInit, so it doesn't change when the input changes.
You should re-init it whenever input changes which you should be able to catch with [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

For passing data from table into the chart component, one way to do it is use @Output to emit result that you enter in table component into the parent component, and then pass it back to the chart. You can read on inputs/outputs [here](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i already tried that but cant seem to figure it out and make it work properly, by any chance you could edit the stackblitz so i can take a look please ?

Comment: @mato4899 hey sorry, no I won't write code for you, but me or someone else can look for mistakes after you try yourself and post updated example with a particular problem

I suggest you try first to make sure chart updates every 10 secs via OnChanges  - chart js might require [smth extra to refresh after the data changes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) (or in worst case just kill/recreate it.
And then learn about passing data using  [inputs/outputs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: For that i can just do setInterval() for 10 secs and inside call initChart method and that works but it defeats the purpose of ngOnChanges. For some reason it doesnt detect the changes made to the @Input() chartData

Comment: @mato4899 `i can just do setInterval() for 10 secs` - you already have that, in your service, and already listen to these changes in main component updating input on the chart component each time, so you should be able to listen to changes of this input using OnChanges .. or you can also inject data service into chart component and subscribe to your observable also there, there's other ways as well.

Comment: i added console.log to the ngOnChanges and its not detecting any changes just the initial one see link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znnnsp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.html,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Flabel%2Flabel.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Flabel%2Flabel.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.ts

Comment: interesting.. might be it keeps reference to the same array so doesn't trigger change detection.. you can try force it changes e.g. by destructuring `this.arr = [...arr]`